# Why is String + '\u0000' different than String?

Tags: java, string, char

My algorithm constructs a word and looks up a value associated with the word in a TST.

```
private Node get(Node x, String key, int index) {
    if (key.isEmpty()) {
        return root;
    }
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    }
    char c = key.charAt(index);
    if (c < x.val) {
        return get(x.left, key, index);
    } else if (c > x.val) {
        return get(x.right, key, index);
    } else if (index < key.length() - 1) {
        return get(x.mid, key, index + 1);
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Each node is constructed as such:

```
private class Node {
    private char val;
    private Node left, mid, right;
    private Double selfWeight;
    private double maxWeight;

    /**
     * Node constructor.
     */
    private Node(char c) {
        val = c;
        maxWeight = 0.0;
        selfWeight = null;
    }
}
```

A word's maxWeight is set during construction, which is a modified version of standard construction of a TST:

```
private Node put(Node x, String key, Double weight, int index) {
    char c = key.charAt(index);
    if (x == null) {
        x = new Node();
        x.val = c;
    }
    if (c < x.val) {
        x.left = put(x.left, key, weight, index);
    } else if (c > x.val) {
        x.right = put(x.right, key, weight, index);
    } else if (index < key.length() - 1) {
        x.mid = put(x.mid, key, weight, index + 1);
    } else {
        x.selfWeight = weight;
    }
    if (weight > x.maxWeight) {
        x.maxWeight = weight;
    }
    return x;
}
```

When running my algorithm, if I insert, for e.g. "hello" with weight 20, and I do search on `get("hello" + '\u0000');` the method will return null where as if I call `get("hello")` the method will return 20. Why is this?

My logic is that adding the 'null' char will not change the string, and printing out `"hello" + '\u0000'` confirms this. What is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not the same string because they don't contain the same characters. Just because you can't see a character doesn't mean it's not there.

If you converted `hello` to unicode then what you're claiming is

`0068 0065 006C 006C 006F 0000` is the same as `0068 0065 006C 006C 006F`

If you need further explanation, go examine the equals method for `String`

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29

```
/**
     * Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is {@code
     * true} if and only if the argument is not {@code null} and is a {@code
     * String} object that represents the same sequence of characters as this
     * object.
     *
     * @param  anObject
     *         The object to compare this {@code String} against
     *
     * @return  {@code true} if the given object represents a {@code String}
     *          equivalent to this string, {@code false} otherwise
     *
     * @see  #compareTo(String)
     * @see  #equalsIgnoreCase(String)
     */
    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
            int n = count;
            if (n == anotherString.count) {
                char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = offset;
                int j = anotherString.offset;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Is there any such thing as a truly empty char?

Comment: if you're asking if there's a ```char``` that is ```null``` then no

Comment: in any case i don't know what you mean by "empty"

Comment: Empty as in conacenation will not change the bit value of the string

Answer (score 2):

> Why is String + '/u0000' different than String?

Because '/u0000' (or NUL) is a valid character, not a string terminator.

A String in Java is a sequence of characters, not a sequence of characters terminated by a NUL (or zero).

---

<sup>(Actually, it is a bit more technically complicated than that.  `/u0000` is a 16-bit UTF-16 code-unit that also happens to be a Unicode code-point.  A String is a sequence of 16-bit `char` values that may or may not be valid UTF-16 code-units and may or may not be a well-formed Unicode code-point sequence.  But either way, the zero char / code-point / code-unit is NOT a string terminator.)</sup>

---

> Is there any such thing as a truly empty char?

No.  Certainly, not in Java.